# Python: overloading the return type for magic methods `__str__` and `__repr__`

Tags: python, inheritance, overloading, type-hinting, mypy

I have a custom enum class that can only return a specific set of string literals when calling `__str__` or `__repr__`. Given that these serialized string literals are sometimes used as input for other functions (and these inputs are well-typed, ie, restricted to the right set of strings), I want the return type of `__str__` and `__repr__` to be more precise than `str`.

Consider the following:

```py
from typing import Literal

class A:
    def __repr__(self) -> Literal["world"]:
        result : Literal["world"] = "world"
        return result

test_val : Literal["world"] = repr(A())
print(test_val)
```

The above SHOULD work, since the type annotations are coherent, yet with mypy, I get:

```
playground.py:8: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "Literal['world']")
```

for the line where I assign `test_val`.

I suspect this might be due to some global mechanism on how dunder method types are defined; and `__repr__` will ALWAYS return a string. But given that I can choose my return type for `__getitem__` just fine, I think something else might be doable.

**Is there any way to force the overloading of the return type of `__str__`/`__repr__` so long as co/contra-variance, Liskov, etc, are respected ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is typed correctly, but you're conflating `repr` and `__repr__`. `A().__repr__()` returns a `Literal["world"]` but `repr`, with signature

```
def repr(x: object) -> str: ...
```

always returns a `str`

Comment: Ah, indeed, `A().__repr__()` does work. Thanks a lot !